# EXISTS is giving me a right parenthesis error, even though all parentheses are there

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query and getting a "missing right parenthesis" error on the EXISTS statement, even though I don't see any missing parentheses.

```
Select 
  t1.ID
  ,t2.NAME
FROM
  TABLE1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
WHERE
  t1.ID=123
  AND
  (EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 AS t3 WHERE t1.ID=t3.ID AND t2.NAME=t3.NAME)
  OR t1.OTHER_THING=1 OR t2.OTHER_THING=1)
```

I basically want the data from t1 and t2 if it exists in t3 OR if the other conditions are true. Why doesn't this work? Correction: it works in MS-SQL but not Oracle.

And I can't post the actual query because I might get in trouble so don't bother asking.

Also, since this isn't copy-pasted, ignore any errors you see above the AND (EXISTS... part. I can take it out and the query runs fine, so it's nothing else above that.

Comment: At minimum, you're missing an `ON` to introduce the join condition in your outer join.

Comment: @mafafu, those changes are not syntactically necessary, and they change the meaning of the query.

Comment: I want the logic to go A and (B or C or D) so any of the things inside the parentheses can be true, along with A. Will removing the parentheses keep this logic? Or could be interpreted as (A and B) or C or D? Or something else?

Comment: Your query as written should be fine.  Are you actually getting the error on *this* query?  If not, be sure your question has the query with an actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it. My query actually had an "AS" between TABLE3 and t3. Removing it fixed it somehow. I can reproduce it by putting the "AS" back in. Weird. MS-SQL doesn't care that it's there, but Oracle gives an error. Thanks for everyone's help, though, especially those who understand that query logic is important ;)

Comment: Yes, Oracle lets you optionally use `AS` for column aliases but not for table aliases. You've also discovered that Oracle errors, particularly this one, shouldn't always be taken at face value *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Your brace before EXISTS is causing the confusion, try this:

```
Select 
  t1.ID
  ,t2.NAME
FROM
  TABLE1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
WHERE
  t1.ID=123
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 t3 WHERE t1.ID=t3.ID AND t2.NAME=t3.NAME)
  OR t1.OTHER_THING=1 OR t2.OTHER_THING=1
```

Comment: That is not the problem and this solution implements different logic from what  the OP is asking for.

Comment: The parenthesis before the `EXISTS` in the OP's query is balanced by one at the end of the statement.  That presents no issue.

Answer (score 0):

The query originally posted had several issues:

- The 'ON' keyword was omitted from the join condition for the outer join
- The table alias "t2" was nowhere declared
- There was apparent confusion between the table aliases "t" and "t1"
- There was a table named "TABLE", which is a keyword, and it was referenced as a bare name

On the other hand, your revised query works for me.